# Sending message to facebook using UE API returning 403 error

Tags: php, unificationengine

I am using [PHP SDK](https://github.com/unifiedinbox/ue-php-sdk) for using UE API [UE](https://developer.unificationengine.com/) in my PHP laravel project. I have createduser and connection successfully and getting right json.But When I am trying to send message using below code I get 403 forbidden error:

```
    $options = array(
        "receivers" => array(
            array(
                "name"=> "Me"
            )
        ),
        "message"=>array(
            "subject"=>"test",
            "body"=> "ABC",
            "image"=>"http://politibits.blogs.tuscaloosanews.com/files/2010/07/sanford_big_dummy_navy_shirt.jpg",
            "link"=>array(
                "uri"=> "http://google.com",
                "description"=> "link desc",
                "title"=>"link title"
            )
        )
    );

    //Send the message and get their uris
    $uris = $connection->send_message($options);
```

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The access token might have expired. Please reconnect the facebook connection again or refresh the connection.

The facebook access tokens have a lifetime of about two hours. For longer lived web apps, especially server side, need to generate long lived tokens. Long lived tokens generally lasts about 60 days.